# How to create an index returning the input document type?

Tags: c#, mapreduce, ravendb

I have a Raven database which contains a document collection. I would like to retrieve a subset of the documents in that collection. Only documents fulfilling certain criteria would be retrieved. However, for each document retrieved, the *entire* document must be retrieved.

Consider the following document type:

```
public class MyDocument {
    public string Id { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Foo { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}
```

Let's say I would like to retrieve all documents where the Foo property is greater than a given value (unknown at compile/index creation time). Using dynamic indexes, this could be done like:

```
IList<MyDocument> FindMyDocuments(int minFooValue) {
    using(IDocumentSession session = _store.OpenSession()) {
        return session.Query<MyDocument>().Where(d => d.Foo > minFooValue).ToList();
    }
}
```

However, as I understand it, there are benefits to using predefined indexes instead of dynamic indexes. So I would like to define an index for this operation up front. *How would an implementation of AbstractIndexCreationTask< MyDocument, MyDocument > look like?*

The following doesn't seem to work as Raven wants the Map to select a new anonymous type:

```
class MyDocumentIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocument, MyDocument> {
    public MyDocumentIndex() {
        Map = docs => from doc from docs
                      select doc;
    }
}
```

And shouldn't there be a Reduce part as well?

As you probably noticed, I'm rather new to this Map/Reduce concept :-).

Answer (score 0):

David,
You do it like this:

```
public class MyDocumentIndex: AbstractIndexCreationTask<MyDocument> {
    public MyDocumentIndex() {
        Map = docs => from doc from docs
                      select new { doc.Foo };
    }
}
```

And then you query it with:

```
session.Query<MyDocument, MyDocumentIndex().Query(x=>x.Foo > minValue).ToArray();
```

Comment: Won't that just give me an array of all values of Foo greater than minValue? I need the entire documents.